# Exception in Library gives " Method '~' of object '~' failed " error randomly

Tags: c#, dll

I have a program that is calling a method from an external library every second.  It will work for weeks where the library is called over 50000 times, then will randomly give me an exception:

```
Method '~' of object '~' failed
```

I have read it could be a problem with the MDAC versions (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255986), but this doesn't make sense to me as it works 99% of the time. The call does not change and neither does the data that it is being given to the method.  I am working in C#, but the library was given with a VB.NET package if that makes a difference.

Comment: The question you linked to as the duplicate does nothing to help me.  It is a question related to VB6, whereas this question is for C#.  Furthermore, OP clearly stated that this issue is intermittent in nature.  The question linked as "duplicate" talks about versioning.  How could a versioning issue be intermittent?

Comment: Oh I see.  This was just house cleaning.  Question asked December, marked duplicate in March.  Even if the question weren't closed, it would still be no help to me, as there were no answers for 3 months.